# How to know which "version" of USB a device is attached as

Tags: usb, kernel, hardware, devices, protocol

What the title says. Is there a way to know if a USB device is registered as oldschool/original USB, USB2, or USB3 etc? I'd guess either from virtual files under /sys or maybe dmesg/kernel logs?

Answer (score 0):

Running `lsusb -v` in terminal will give you what you're looking for.
Specficially, look for the `bcdUSB` entry to see what the USB version is.

Running `lsusb --tree` will also show each device and it's speed. You can infer the USB version based on those speeds.